# formatação encoding .net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, codificação-de-caracteres

tudo bem?
To com um problema que é o seguinte: eu recupero o html de um sistema legado e, preciso alterar esse html pa depois retornar pro browser com o novo html.
Mas qndo recupero esse relatório as palavras com ç e acentos, estão com caracteres especias, ex.: Impress�o.
OBS.: Esse problema ocorre qndo o html é recuperado, pois a pagina recuperada, executada sem problemas em produção.

O charset utilizado nessa pagina é iso-8859-1.
Utilizo webrequest

```
 var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
 var response = request.GetResponse();
 var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 htmlFicha = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Tentei, fazer replace, pra substiuir pela palavra correta, mas tb num deu certo.
Como faço, pra corrigir esse problema?
muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente passar o `Encoding` desejado como parâmetro no `StreamReader`:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), true);
htmlFicha = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: kra vlw...deu certo!!!!! muitíssimo obrigado

Comment: Por nada, abraço ;)